# How to iterate two separate arrays in handlebars Nodejs with {{#each}}?

Tags: mysql, node.js, loops, handlebars.js, server-side-rendering

I am creating a Risk Management System using Nodejs and Express with Handlebar views. Using SQL, I am extracting two queries in my GET router and rendering them to the handlebar view. This is how it looks:

```
const parametro = await pool.query('select * from parametro where parid = ?', [parid]);
const tipoParametros = await pool.query('select distinct tipoparid from tipoparametro order by tipoparid');

res.render('parametros/modificar', {parametro, tipoParametros});
```

I consoled logged both arrays and they look like these:

```
- parametro: [
  RowDataPacket {
    parid: 22,
    parcodigo: 'TEST',
    tipoparid: 11,
    pardescripcion: 'Just a Test',
    parexplicacion: 'Test',
    parclasificacion: 3,
    parvalor: 'Test 1',
    parusrcreaid: null,
    parfechacrea: 2022-06-25T21:58:19.000Z,
    parusrmodid: null,
    parfechamod: null
  }
]
- tipoParametros: [ RowDataPacket { tipoparcodigo: 'SYS', tipoparid: 11 } ]
```

However, since my POST for this view needs :id, I am iterating with each parametro because that's how I keep track of each row in my database, with parid. The .hbs view looks like this:

```
{{#each parametro}}
<form class = "row g-3 needs-validation" method = "POST" action = "/parametros/modificar/{{this.parid}}" novalidate>
    {{> formparametro}}
</form>
{{/each}}
```

and inside "formparametro" there is a form-floating section where I try to iterate with each tipoParametro but nothing is coming out. Looks like this:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <select class="form-select" id="floatingSelect" name="tipoparid" aria-label="Floating label select example" required>
            {{#each tipoParametros}}
            <option value={{this.tipoparid}}>{{this.tipoparcodigo}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
        <label for="floatingSelect">Tipo Parametro</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I have access to the query and columns of tipoParametro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `formparametro` partial is rendered within your `{{#each parametro}}` block, the context for each time the partial is rendered is the currently iterated item from `parametro`. Therefore, the partial has no access to `tipoParametros`.

What we want to do is provide a context to our partial that *does* contain `tipoParametros`. This is very simple. The Handlebars documentation covers [Partial Contexts](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partial-contexts) and it states that a context can be supplied to the partial as the second parameter within the mustache brackets, as in:

`{{> myPartial myOtherContext }}`

As your `tipoParametros` object belongs to your root context, I would recommend using the [`@root` data variable](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#root) to pass the root context to your partial. The line in your template invoking your partial thus becomes:

`{{> formparametro @root}}`

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/ohu39bjf/) for your reference.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you so much! This allowed me to render both blocks while keeping my router post intact. Appreciate it!

Comment: @MarlonMiller: You're very welcome, I'm glad this was helpful to you. I would appreciate an up-vote or for you to mark this answer as accepted.